# Adding Total in child grouping for SSRS power bi reporting

Tags: reporting-services, power-bi-report-server

I am expecting to get the total as below.
I have parent group of batchid and child group of employeename.
I'm having difficulties to get the total after grouping .
how can i get total =7 and =3677.19

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnBjE.png)

I tried to use =Sum(CountDistinct(Fields!EmployeeName.Value))

Comment: right-click your outside row group and choose "add total - below"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.